# How to determine index of currently formatted TableView Cell

Tags: java, javafx

I have two dimensional array of objects of one type. I want to format each table cell based on its data, row and column index. Therefore i must know exactly which cell of TableView i am currently formatting. I couldn't find method which gives current cell index inside updateItem in the setCellFactory. Here is the whole code for creating TableView:

```
private TableView<String[]> createTableView() {

    String data[][] = { { "a", "b", "c", "d" }, { "f", "f", "h", "h" }, { "i", "a", "k", "a" } };

    TableView<String[]> tview = new TableView<String[]>();

    ObservableList<String[]> obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        obList.add(data[i]);

    tview.setItems(obList);

    for (int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        TableColumn<String[], String> col = new TableColumn<String[], String>(data[0][i]);

        final int colNo = i;            
        col.setCellValueFactory( param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[colNo]) );
        tview.getColumns().add(col);

        col.setCellFactory( column -> {
            return new TableCell<String[], String>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null && !empty) {
                        int row = getIndex();
                        int col = 0;//??? how to determine which column is it
                        setText("["+row+","+col+"] " + item);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    }
    return tview;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure which index you are trying to get, but in your cell implementation the column index is just `colNo`, and you can get the row index by calling `getIndex()`.